# document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex(ind).value

Tags: javascript, html

Есть HTML код:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction('2')">Try it</button>
```

Как сделать функцию Javascript, которая будет определять `selectedIndex` элемента `mySelect` и узнавать значение `value`? Т.е. что-то вроде этого:

```
function myFunction(ind) {
  alert(document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex(ind).value);
}
```

И в итоге должен вывести "Pineapple".

Упростить этот вариант у меня не получится, там долгая история. Мне придётся копировать код всей страницы, чтобы Вам понять зачем мне такие сложности.

Comment: Думаю Вы поняли, что мне надо %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, можно делать просто так:

```js
function myFunction(ind) {
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  select.selectedIndex = ind;
  alert(select.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(ind) {
    return document.getElementById("mySelect").options[ind].text;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: А точнее - хотя бы описание вашей идеи.

Comment: @Regent: Не обязательно выбирать элемент чтобы узнать его значение. То есть вместо document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex можно подставлять свой индекс.

Comment: Да мне-то можно не объяснять. Важно добавить объяснение в сам ответ. Как для автора, так и для будущих читателей.